# Assign Static Public Address to Azure Container Instance deployment

Tags: azure, containers, azure-application-gateway, azure-traffic-manager, azure-load-balancer

## Context

Working on a project to deploy a restful API application and seperate TCP service to an Azure Container Instance. The TCP service requires a static Ipv4 address due to legacy reasons.

[image: ContextDiagram]

## Question

I am attempting to isolate my options to assign as static public IP address to the TCP service hosted on an Azure Container Instance. What are the options ?

## Tested

1. Deployed Azure Application Gateway with a static public IP address. The App Gateway allows backend pool to be directed to an IP or FQDN endpoint. This appears to be operational (see diagram). Altough the options from the backend pool appear to allow HTTP and HTTPS only , not custom ports. Maybe this can be manipulated if the TCP service can listen on 80 and web API on 443. App gateway is Layer 7 resource for HTTP and HTTPS traffic only.
2. Azure Load Balancer. Could only be directed at the VM, Availablity Set or VM Scale Set.
3. Assign static address to the Resource. Not allowed for Container Instances.
4. Traffic Manager. Doesn't appear to be the correct type of resource for this deployment.

See diagram. The Container Instances for API and TCP SERVICE have the same private IP address when I query via a BASH session. Suggested they are hosted on the same host (labled as Container Group) in the attached diagram. Not sure if that is the correct label sorry, I am new to Container tech.

Thank you for any advice.
Scott

Answer (score 25, accepted):

## Possible Solution

May have a solution:

- Created a new VNET
- Address range 10.60.0.0/23
- Created subnet Containers 10.60.0.0/24
- Created VNET Firewall resource
- Created subnet Firewall 10.60.1.0/24
- Assigned Static Public Address to Firewall Resource

Now the Firewall "Rules" allow for the following:

- NAT rules - typical port translation
- Network Rules - route addresses
- Application Rules - route FQDN

Working to deploy the container to this dev subnet , on the face of it all the options are there , redirect port, ip or FQDN. The game changes is teh ability to assign a static public address to a resource within the VNET and allow NAT, network or app rules to redirect traffic.

Will update the thread on result tomorrow.

## Update Feb 2019

Ok so dont use an Azure Firewall Resource. Its very expensive and in my case not in anyway cost effective @ approx £500 per month. I did not get the time to test the theory using the firewall , but due to the cost there was not any point in following it further.

Azure Container Instances enables exposing containers directly to the internet with an IP address and a fully qualified domain name (FQDN). When you create a container instance, you can specify a custom DNS name label so your application is reachable at customlabel.azureregion.azurecontainer.io. Unfortunately  Static Public IP addresses are not supported on ACI at the moment.

Certain limitations apply when you deploy container groups to a virtual network.

- To deploy container groups to a subnet, the subnet cannot contain any other resource types. Remove all existing resources from an existing subnet prior to deploying container groups to it, or create a new subnet.
- Container groups deployed to a virtual network do not currently support public IP addresses or DNS name labels.
- Due to the additional networking resources involved, deploying a container group to a virtual network is typically somewhat slower than deploying a standard container instance.

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/602224-azure-container-instances

## Solution Deployed

- Ubuntu VM created using Azure Image
- Static public address assigned to the VM
- Api and Service deployed in docker image to the VM
- Arm template used for deployment , integrated with DevOps build and release
- Cost per month £23.52  (Cores: 2, 3GB ram, 16GB HD)

This was initially the solution but offloading and managing the SSL cert added complexity.

## Update March 2019 - New Solution Deployed

If anyone is interested (not many base on the number of times this thread has been viewed) the final solution deployed was this:

- Provision App Service Plan
- Deployed "API" App Service using a Container Instance to host the API on port 443.
- Dynamic address and standard SSL cert deployed to "API" App Service.
- Deployed "Service" App Service using a Container Instance to host the Service port 80.
- Static address and IP based SSL cert deployed to "Service" App Service. This has the effect of fixing the IP address on the service and meeting my "i need a static ip address" condition.
- Costs about £65 a month to host approx.

Worth noting the only reason the cert was deployed was to fix the IP address on the "Service" app service. Its a work around to resolve the lack of support on Azure currently to allow users to apply a static IP address to a container instance.

[image]

## Update March 2020

Post updated in March for reference due to the introduction of the following feature 20/03/20:

This article shows one way to expose a static, public IP address for a container group by using an Azure application gateway. Follow these steps when you need a static entry point for an external-facing containerized app that runs in Azure Container Instances.

In this article you use the Azure CLI to create the resources for this scenario:

- An Azure virtual network
- A container group deployed in the virtual network (preview) that hosts a small web app
- An application gateway
  with a public frontend IP address, a listener to host a website on
  the gateway, and a route to the backend container group

As long as the application gateway runs and the container group exposes a stable
private IP address in the network's delegated subnet, the container group is accessible at this public IP address.

**Create virtual network**

```
az group create --name myResourceGroup --location eastus
```

Create a virtual network with the az network vnet create command. This command creates the myAGSubnet subnet in the network.

```
az network vnet create \
  --name myVNet \
  --resource-group myResourceGroup \
  --location eastus \
  --address-prefix 10.0.0.0/16 \
  --subnet-name myAGSubnet \
  --subnet-prefix 10.0.1.0/24
```

Use the az network vnet subnet create command to create a subnet for the backend container group. Here it's named myACISubnet.

```
az network vnet subnet create \
  --name myACISubnet \
  --resource-group myResourceGroup \
  --vnet-name myVNet   \
  --address-prefix 10.0.2.0/24
```

Use the az network public-ip create command to create a static public IP resource. In a later step, this address is configured as the front end of the application gateway.

```
az group create --name myResourceGroup --location eastus

az network public-ip create \
  --resource-group myResourceGroup \
  --name myAGPublicIPAddress \
  --allocation-method Static \
  --sku Standard
```

**Create container group**

Run the following az container create to create a container group in the virtual network you configured in the previous step.

The group is deployed in the myACISubnet subnet and contains a single instance named appcontainer that pulls the aci-helloworld image. As shown in other articles in the documentation, this image packages a small web app written in Node.js that serves a static HTML page.

```
az container create \
  --name appcontainer \
  --resource-group myResourceGroup \
  --image mcr.microsoft.com/azuredocs/aci-helloworld \
  --vnet myVNet \
  --subnet myACISubnet
```

When successfully deployed, the container group is assigned a private IP address in the virtual network. For example, run the following az container show command to retrieve the group's IP address:

```
az container show \
  --name appcontainer --resource-group myResourceGroup \
  --query ipAddress.ip --output tsv
```

Output is similar to: 10.0.2.4.

For use in a later step, save the IP address in an environment variable:

```
ACI_IP=$(az container show \
  --name appcontainer \
  --resource-group myResourceGroup \
  --query ipAddress.ip --output tsv)
```

**Create application gateway**

Create an application gateway in the virtual network, following the steps in the application gateway quickstart. The following az network application-gateway create command creates a gateway with a public frontend IP address and a route to the backend container group. See the Application Gateway documentation for details about the gateway settings.

```
az network application-gateway create \
  --name myAppGateway \
  --location eastus \
  --resource-group myResourceGroup \
  --capacity 2 \
  --sku Standard_v2 \
  --http-settings-protocol http \
  --public-ip-address myAGPublicIPAddress \
  --vnet-name myVNet \
  --subnet myAGSubnet \
  --servers "$ACI_IP"
```

It can take up to 15 minutes for Azure to create the application gateway.

Test public IP address
Now you can test access to the web app running in the container group behind the application gateway.

Run the az network public-ip show command to retrieve the frontend public IP address of the gateway:

```
az network public-ip show \
--resource-group myresourcegroup \
--name myAGPublicIPAddress \
--query [ipAddress] \
--output tsv
```

Output is a public IP address, similar to: 52.142.18.133.

To view the running web app when successfully configured, navigate to the gateway's public IP address in your browser. Successful access is similar to:

Browser screenshot showing application running in an Azure container instance

Ref
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-application-gateway

## Jan 2021

Final edit to document this article from July 2020 in which you can you set up container groups in a virtual network behind an Azure firewall. You configure a user-defined route and NAT and application rules on the firewall. By using this configuration, you set up a single, static IP address for ingress and egress from Azure Container Instances.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-egress-ip-address

Documents the use of:

- container group
- azure firewall
- reserved public ip
- routing traffic

The down side is the expense of the Azure Firewall resource. That aside the solution works.

[image: Azure Firewall Cost]

## Aug 2022

Another project and this issue has popped up again. Its possible Azure Load Balancer which currently only supports VM backend pools may support Azure Container Instances (ACI) some time soon.

Project 1

In the mean time we needed a single instance container to serve FW images to devices over a TCP connection. Devices look for a server IP endpoint. So hosting in an ACI resource the service does a DNS lookup on the azurecontainerregistery.io host name and serves the device with the most recent public IP address. Device then routes in to the IP resource. Handy work around for us when server side is initiating the command to a device polling into another service.

Project 2

In regards to the other device service , finding hosting a container on a Azure D-Series VM behind an Azure Load Balancer and attaching an Azure Reserved IP to the WAN (front end interface) of the Load Balancer is working ok. But to run Docker on the VM you need an expensive D series resource. Still cheaper than Azure Firewall. An alternative is running as a windows service on the VM, allows the use of a $11 VM resource but this small VM cannot support containers if using Windows OS.

Long Term

Think the ideal situation would be Azure Load Balancer with a fixed public IP pointing at a backend pool of multiple small cheap ACI instances so we don't have to worry about OS management. Azure VM Scale Set for the back end pool resources also have some pretty nice auto scale tools and Dev Ops integration.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for all of the edits. Mind if I ask how much this last setup is costing you? The one with the application gateway?

Comment: Morning Cameron. Largest cost was the standard tier application gateway at approx £130 GDP pm. Entire resource group (app gateway, container instance, vnet and storage account approx £170 GDP pm). Hope that helps. Scott

Comment: Yes it does, I appreciate it.

Comment: Hey, need a single, static IP address for my setup, too. But, as you might already know, 700 bucks is just too expensive for it ;) Am I / are wo doing something wrong? Or is this really the intended solution? Seams like there must be a better way?

Comment: Morning. We have tried a few. App Gateway is layer 7, gets you a static public address using SSL to fix IP but allows http https so depends on what you are deploying. Windows firewall is expensive yes but works a resources in front of a container and setup routes for the traffic. Also if you deploy ACI you get a azurecontainer.io URL which you can point a CNAME at too. In some of our uses cases that works as IoT edge devices are DNS aware. Testing a VM and ACI in a VNET too but essential does what a Windows Firewall does. Can probably use NAT or Add Route on a cheap VM to mimic Azure Firewall.

Comment: @scott_lotus Doesn't the ACI_IP change the moment the ACI is restarted? How will this setup work in the long term if the gateway is pointing to the private IP address of the container group?

Comment: So the IP can change due start,stop,restart,delete,create. ACI can expose your container groups to the net via public IP and FQDN.  When you create a container instance, you can specify a custom DNS name yourACI.azurecontainer.io.
The main difference between application gateway and load balancer is the traffic can be routed using path base routing and not using the IP and the port. The Application Gateway is using the FQDN. Hope that helps. Scott

Comment: @scott_lotus yes but if you expose the ACI via public IP and FQDN, then it cannot be inside a vnet, so can't access a database or any other private resources it needs. That is the main problem I have. Unlike a normal VM, you can't add a public IP to it.  And when the ACI gets restarted (which it does so very often on its own), the application gateway will have the wrong address.

Comment: FYI for those considering using Application Gateways, because the private IP of the ACI is not static it can still change, which will require you to update the backend IP of the gateway
https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/61627

Comment: Would the following be an option? On the app service, where the app runs, add a private endpoint.  Use the Azure Load Balancer, public IP in front and a ip based backend pool.  Select the endpoint as target in the backend pool? I have tested it, I could not get it to work though ...

Comment: Traefik might be an option as a "load balancer". It's actually a reverse proxy. https://traefik.io/

Comment: I followed this yet no luck https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-application-gateway

Is there a better way to achieve this - even if a range of IP's, It doesn't need to be a single fixed IP.

I am able to get the aci-helloworld example working but that is of course not an application that runs in the real world. Do I need to listen on port 80 regardless?