# Can you assign a static public ip address for a azure container instance

Tags: azure-container-instances

I have a project where I need to load data into a mysql database. I need to whitelist an IP address in order to do the insertion and I was planning on using Azure container instances to load data into the database. But, Azure containers change their ip after every run. So are you able to bind a static outbound public ip address to containers? I do not want to use azure firewall gateway since that's too expensive and while I got the process working on a linux vm, a container would suit my needs better since I just need to run a script several times a day.

Comment: There are multiple solutions on this thread. Please check if they help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53815807/assign-static-public-address-to-azure-container-instance-deployment?rq=1